# removing links from dataset

Tags: python, excel, twitter, hyperlink

I have the following dataset and I need to remove all of the links from it. The csv looks like this:

[image: data]

Does anyone know how I can quickly and easily do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression in python as such:

```
import re 

for x in list :
     re.sub("http\S*\s", "", x)
```

where list is a list of your csv data.

This is the code I use to preprocess Twitter Data:

```
all_text  = re.sub("#\S*\s", "", all_text)
all_text  = re.sub("W+", "", all_text)
all_text  = re.sub("@\S*\s", "", all_text)
all_text  = re.sub("http\S*\s", "", all_text)
```

Comment: This is a package I've also found useful: https://pypi.org/project/tweet-preprocessor/

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much! That tweet-preprocessor package was SOOOO helpful! Answered my question and so much more!